# Apache Spark Streaming: accumulate data in memory and output it only much later

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, pyspark, apache-flink

If I understand this right, spark streaming is for piping your RDD batches through a set of transformations with an output operation after the transformations. This is executed for each batch so the output operation, too, is executed for each batch. But since doing output each time is far to expensive, I would like to process the batches and accumulate the results, and only at some event (e.g. after a certain time period) write out the accumulated results and end the program.

I know I can accumulate data e.g. with `updateStateByKey` but I don't know how to tell Spark to use an output operation (e.g. `saveAsTextFiles`) only much later, when some condition arrived.

Is this possible at all?

Is this possible in flink?

Answer (score 3):

**Disclaimer:** I am an contributer to Apache Flink.

It should be possible to do this with Flink, due to rich window semantics: http://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/apis/streaming_guide.html#window-operators
Flink has a bunch of pre-defined windows. Additionally, you can implement your own windowing policy to get customized behavior as you need it.

Comment: but HOW should it be possible?

Comment: Did you follow the link? It explains how it works in Flink. Or please, specify a more detailed question.

Comment: I agree with Matthias, it sounds like what you want to do is run a computation for a while (some time, or some number of elements) and then act on that result. Running computation over a stream for "a while" is exactly windowing.

The remaining question is: What do you want to do with the data after that? Write it into a new file each time? Append it to an existing one?

Comment: What I do not understand is what you mean by "reduce the incoming data" and "memorise it with updateStateByKey"?

 - you assume that the number of tuples is to large to fit into distributed main-memory of the cluster?
 - you assume that the "reduced batches" fit into distributed main-memory?
  - you assume that further aggregate "reduced batches" into a state?

If this are your assumptions, you could use two consecutive windows. The first "reduces your batches" (-> window of a fixed size of tuples) and the second aggregates your stateByKey and emits the state after a certain period.

Comment: If I used windows, they would become far to large. I thought I could reduce each batch and submit a much smaller amount of data to state with updateStateByKey and then, at the end, process the contents of the state. But this doesn't seem to work. (I here presume that an RDD has to fit into the cluster RAM. Is that true? Or what is the maximum size of an RDD?)

Comment: I never worked with Spark. So I don't know.
However, in Flink, you can used two consecutive window operators to achieve this. The first window is of fixed sizes (ie, fixed number of tuples) and pre-aggregates your incoming data. The second window consumes pre-agg values and compute the global result. The second window can be defined as a time window, such that you receive the current global state periodically (once a second).